# Stepwise regression - print intercept value

Tags: r, variables, select, regression

I am doing a step wise regression for Y on 32 X variables. it is an iterative process where I do the stepwise for 100 different data set. If the Stepwise for Y1 turns out to be "-infinity" (no optimum model) then the Y should be equal to just the 'intercept valu', which I will use to find Prediction error. Is there any way i can do this in R to print the intercept value if no stepwise exist?
Any help would be appreciated.

More Information:
Sorry for being unclear on what is required. Here is what I have:
I have 36 predictor and one response model. Initially I have 50 observations. Now I need to do stepwise regression on these 50 observations to see which variables are significant. 
Then in the second iteration I add 10 more observations (total 60) and again run stepwise to study variable significance. So I am trying to improve the model sequentially by adding points. 
So when doing stepwise, if the result is negative infinity, which means none of the variable is significance and so value of y will just be the intercept. If stepwise was successful then it will spit out a model with variables that are significant. 
Once I get the stepwise model I find the error using a validation data set.
So for particular iteration if stepwise is negative infinity then the error is (actual Y - intercept/actual Y), if the stepwise exist then prediction error = (actual y - Y hat/actual Y)
Actual y is from validation set and Y hat is from stepwise regression (training set).

My requirement is if the stepwise is negative infinity, can R give me intercept value instead of telling me out of bounds.

```
for(i in 1:length(tn2_1)){
fit1[[i]] <- lm(Y1~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10+x11+x12+x13+x14+x15+x16+x17+x18+x19+x20+x21+x22+x23+x24+x25+x26+x27+x28+x29+x30+x31+x32,data=d1[[i]] [,c(1:32,33)])
}
    for(i in 1:length(tn2_1)){
stepY1[[i]] <- stepAIC(fit1[[i]],  direction="forward")
stepY1[[i]]$anova # display results
summary(stepY1[[i]])
}
```

This is my code I got, so if stepY1 is negative infinity it should give me the intercept value  `coef(fit1[[1]])["(Intercept)"])`

Let me kow if this explains.
Thanks

Comment: In the absence of an example of data with say 4 or 5 variables and a few data-objects, one of which throws this poorly described "infinity valu", this question is incoherent, i.e. makes no sense.

Comment: Yes I certainly understand why negative infinity, mostly because of lack of data points. In this study I am trying to increase the data points per each iteration to see how well the model fits. And so if its negative infinity it has to give me just the intercept (since coeff of all x's 0) else it should give me the stepwise result.

Comment: The question remains only slightly less incoherent. Please provide a reproducible example and explain in detail what you wnat to be the result of whatever process you imagine being applied to the example data.